# What does combined block caching option 'DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE|DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE' do?

Tags: 7, blocks, caching

I understand that certain block caching options can be combined. What does it mean if I set the caching option of a block defined in code to `DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE|DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE`?

I am confused by the OR bitwise operator. Does this mean that the block will not only be cached by page, but also by role? For example, if User role A visits the same page as User role B, they will each see different cached versions of the block despite being on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/group/block_caching/7.x):

> Page and user settings can be combined with a bitwise-binary or operator; for example, `DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE | DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE` means that the block can change depending on the user role or page it is on.

In other words: When the block is cached, information about the user role and page are stored with it. The cached version is served only in situations where both the current user role *and* the current page match those of the cached block.

A good example in Drupal 7 core is the Author Information block (see [block info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21profile%21profile.module/function/profile_block_info/7.x), [block view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!profile!profile.module/function/profile_block_view/7.x)). It must vary by page, because every page can have a different author, and it must vary by role, because not every role may have permissions to view the author information.